# Should the (analysis) tag be deprecated?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Currently, the [analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis)  [tag description](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/analysis/info) reads:

> Mathematical Analysis generally, including Real Analysis, Harmonic Analysis, Complex Variable Theory, the Calculus of Variations, Measure Theory, and Non-Standard Analysis.

Each of these areas has its own specific tag, and all except the [nonstandard-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nonstandard-analysis) tag are fairly frequently used. It would seem to me that essentially all analysis questions fit into at most 2 or 3 of these areas, and so it would be more appropriate to tag them more specifically. Normally the practice would be to remove the tag, but this is not feasible right now given that there are currently 1900 questions tagged [analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis).

Accordingly, I propose that the tag wiki be edited to say that the tag has been deprecated, as was done with the [algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra) tag (which I believe has since been deleted). It seems to me like this situation parallels the situation with the [algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra) tag quite closely. However, since this is such a heavily-used tag, I want to check with the community before acting.

Should the [analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis) tag be deprecated?

Comment: BTW there was a discussion about this in tagging chatroom not so long ago, see [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5607136#5607136) and [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5656663#5656663).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks, done.

Comment: I don't think the analysis tag should be removed or declared deprecated. There are similarly general tags such as (general-topology), (probability), for example. Also, I disagree that the situation is entirely similar to the (algebra) situation, where (as far as I understood) the main reason was that it was used from the beginning for two rather disjoint topics which are now tagged (algebra-precalculus) and (abstract-algebra). I don't see a similar situation in the analysis section here.

Comment: @t.b. Maybe it would be useful to post your comment as an answer, so that people can upvote/downvote it...?